# How to get a nice API Plot in Python?

Tags: python, api, matplotlib, plot

I have an algorithm which automatically plots data on the plot area of my GUI. There are the codes I use to do so:

```
self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
self.graph = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, master=self.root)
self.canvas.show()
self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

And here is how I display the relevant points onto the plot area:

```
if eigenvalue > self.eigenvalueThreshold:
  if self.previousEigenvalue <= self.eigenvalueThreshold:
    main.graph.scatter(windowNumber, eigenvalue, c="red")
  else:
    main.graph.scatter(windowNumber, eigenvalue, c="yellow")
else:
  main.graph.scatter(windowNumber, eigenvalue, c="blue")
  self.previousEigenvalue = eigenvalue
  main.canvas.show()
```

I get something like this, where the zoom is automatically done in function of the weight of the set of data points:

[image: http://hpics.li/14e5717]

I would like to know if there is any chance to plot my data like this:

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: look into the seaborn package http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're wanting, it's easier to use `fill_between`, rather than `fill`.  If you use `fill`, you'll have to worry about adding verticies to create a closed polygon.  `fill_between` automatically fills the area between the data and a constant value (0, by default) or another curve.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data to plot...
x = np.arange(1000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, y.size).cumsum()
y[y < 0] *= -1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Fill the region between your curve and 0 with red...
ax.fill_between(x, y, facecolor='red', edgecolor='none')

# Optional...
ax.grid(True, color='white', linewidth=2, linestyle='-')
ax.set(axisbelow=True, axis_bgcolor='lightgray')
ax.tick_params(direction='out')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [matplotlib.pyplot.fill(*args, **kwargs)](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However, when I use _fill_ instead of _scatter_, nothing is displayed on the graph. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: You can't just use fill instead of scatter. You need to generate the outline for your polygon, which probably just involves adding a couple of points for the lower-right and lower-left corner of the area you are filling.

Comment: Thank you. I need to plot dynamically, I can't store a set of data before I plot..

Comment: You don't need to store a set of data before you plot. You just need to append to the data you are already plotting, some coordinates, representing the lower corners of the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a histogram plot:

using this reference: http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/pcfb/numpympl/MatplotlibBarPlots.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
numBins = 50
ax.hist(x,numBins,color='green',alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```